# How can I do this with list comprehension? Or how can I extract every even position element from list and store it in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, list-comprehension

```py
p = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('p.card-text')]
j = []
for i in p:
     if p.index(i)%2 == 0:
          j.append(i)
```

- I am doing this because I only want to extract even position element from my list p.
- Is there any other way to do this (to get only even position element from list)?
- If not, how can I write the code above using list comprehension? I have extracted even position element using this code. I want to know of any other method I can apply or how to write list comprehension for the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following by using `list comprehension` along with `enumerate` in python

```py
p = [i.text.strip() for index,i in enumerate(soup.select('p.card-text')) if index%2==0]
```

Comment: The start parameter is not giving the desired output, without it, the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Um... simply slice:

```
j = p[::2]
```

Or if `select` returns a `list` (looks like it does), do it earlier to save work:

```
soup.select('p.card-text')[::2]
```